# HTML DIV is not sitting under the parents div

Tags: html, css

I am having issues to create 3 columns with CSS, without tables. The 3 `<div>`s that I create aren't sitting under the parent `<div>`. I have to use inline styles for some reason. Below is the code:

```
    <div id="wrapper" style="border:thin solid red;width:520px;margin:auto;">

     <div id="header" style="border:thin solid blue;position:relative;margin:auto;">

        <div id="left_header" style="border:thin solid yellow;float:left;width:105px;position:relative;">
            left header
        </div><!-- closing div tag id=left_header -->

        <div id="center_header" style="border:thin solid grey;float:left;width:50%;">
            center header
        </div><!-- closing div tag id=center_header -->

        <div id="right_header" style="border:thin solid black;float:right;width:120px;">
            right header
        </div><!-- closing div tag id=right_header -->

    </div><!-- closing div tag id=header -->

</div><!-- closing div tag id=wrapper -->
```

The `<div>`s `left_header`, `center_header` and `right_header` are not sitting inside the div header. What am I missing here?

Please help me, I have tried to fix this but I am quite new in web development. I have tried using relative positioning for `left_header` and `center_header` and `absolute` for `right_header`. It still did not fix the issue.

Note:
The code has been tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE8. All do the same thing.

Sample:
[image: Sample for 3 columns through CSS.]

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like they are inside the header div to me. Can you provide a sample page or give us more of the code to show the problem you are having?

Comment: Sample has been added at your request. You can see that the left_header, center_header and right_header are sitting outside the wrapper and header. If I remove the floating from left_header, center_header and right_header, they will sit correctly under the wrapper and header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating left will work, but really the solution to your problem is to use `overflow:auto`. This means that your div will resize to fit the floated content, but will not have it's own position affected [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/BrD78/)

Answer (score 1):

use float:left in your wrapper div [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kj5Yc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
add float:left or overflow:auto; to header style

like
<div id="header" style="border:thin solid blue;position:relative;margin:auto;float:left;">
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys. The answer is adding overflow:auto to my div header. It has fixed my issue. Once again thank you so much for your help. I have learnt something new today.